# How to make an extra icon in QLineEdit like this?

Tags: qt4

I would like to implemented a "clean" button like the following screenshot in Qt Creator, the button dwells in QLineEdit, not a single widget

[image]

Where should I start from ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See this blog entry for a proposed solution:
[Lineedit with a clear button](https://web.archive.org/web/20130730091726/http://blog.qt.digia.com:80/blog/2007/06/06/lineedit-with-a-clear-button/).

---

The main idea is to add a `QToolButton` to the `QLineEdit` and position it properly.

```
LineEdit::LineEdit(QWidget *parent)
    : QLineEdit(parent)
{
    int height = sizeHint().height();
    int btnSize = sizeHint().height() - 5;

    clearButton = new QToolButton(this);
    QPixmap pixmap(":clear.png");
    clearButton->setIcon(QIcon(pixmap));
    clearButton->setCursor(Qt::ArrowCursor);
    clearButton->setStyleSheet("QToolButton { border: none; padding: 2px}");
    clearButton->setFixedSize(btnSize, btnSize);
    clearButton->hide();

    int frameWidth = style()->pixelMetric(QStyle::PM_DefaultFrameWidth);
    setStyleSheet(QString("QLineEdit { padding-right: %1px }")
                                                .arg(btnSize - frameWidth));
    setMinimumHeight(height);

    connect(clearButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(clear()));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(textChanged(const QString&)), 
            this, SLOT(updateCloseButton(const QString&)));
}

void LineEdit::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *)
{
    int frameWidth = style()->pixelMetric(QStyle::PM_DefaultFrameWidth);
    clearButton->move(width() - clearButton->width() - frameWidth, 0);
}

void LineEdit::updateCloseButton(const QString& text)
{
    clearButton->setVisible(!text.isEmpty());
}
```

Also, since Qt 5.2 it is possible to use the `QLineEdit` built-in method [`setClearButtonEnabled`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#clearButtonEnabled-prop).

Comment: Please don't post an answer consisting only of a link, instead include the solution in your answer. This policy is defends against cases like this one, where webpage you link to has changed and no longer has a solution to this question.